The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String? Function()'
I'm doing unit test in a login, but it shows me this error in the password.
The email and password are from LoinUsecaseInput since it is what you receive to login but it shows me error in when(() => mockSharedPreferences.getString(email)).thenReturn('jg3kifei'), specifically in 'jg3kifei', and it is not a “String?” it is only a “String”.
Code:
  late MockSharedPreferences mockSharedPreferences;
  late LoginUseCaseInput loginUseCaseInput;

  setUp(() {
    mockSharedPreferences = MockSharedPreferences();
    loginUseCaseInput = LoginUseCaseInput('email', 'password');
  });

    test('login debe devolver true cuando la caché contiene la entrada de contraseña', () {

      String email = 'prueba4@gmail.com';
      String password = 'jg3kifei8s';
      
      when(() => mockSharedPreferences.getString(email)).thenReturn('jg3kifei');
      final result = LoginUseCaseInput(email, password);
      expect(result, true);
    });

